# Numeric value '2021-06-09 06:56:26.702' is not recognized

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have data share view in snowflake which is having around 470 records but while selecting it i am getting "Numeric value '2021-06-09 06:56:26.702' is not recognized" for Numeric(38,0) datatype column. I tried of using try_to_number, try_cast to avoid it but getting error like "Function TRY_CAST cannot be used with arguments of types NUMBER(38,5) and NUMBER(38,0)". Can anyone please help me on resolving it or please suggest me that do i need to contact source team?

Comment: That’s not a number, it’s timestamp. The underlying datatype is either a timestamp or a string. What’s the datatype in the underlying table and what is the sql statement used by the view?

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have a timestamp into a numeric column.
This is easily reproducible like in below screenshot:

[image]

You will need to change the field type if you want to accommodate timestamp values.